# Index of $Z(G)$ in the centralizer of an element of a finite 2-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite 2-group. Let $x$ be a non-central element of $G$ such that $C_G(x)\leq cl(x)\cup Z(G)$ where $cl(x)$ denotes the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$. 
Is it true that $|C_G(x):Z(G)|=2$?

**p.s.**
I know that if $|G|\leq 2^8$ then the equality holds.

Comment: Why do you think this should be true? Why do you want it to be true, i.e. where does this question originate?

Comment: Do you have any counterexample?

Comment: I can't speak for others, but personally I would like to know some of the motivation behind a question before spending time thinking about it

Comment: Yes, but what prompted you to check this in the first place? I assume this was not just a question that occurred to you out of the blue, so why not give us some more background?

Comment: Basic observations: $C_G(x)/Z(G)$ is an elementary 2-group, and $C_G(x) \subset Z_2(G)$ (from the upper central series).

Comment: @Carnahan The latter assertion looks incorrect. Note that this forces $C_x (G)$ to be normal in $G$.

Answer (score 9):

So all nontrivial elements of $C_G(x)/Z(G)$ are conjugate in $G/Z(G)$.

*Lemma*. If $X$ is a 2-group with a subgroup $Y$ in which all nontrivial elements of $Y$ are conjugate in $X$, then $|Y| \le 2$.

*Proof*. Induction on $|X|$. It's clear if $X$ is abelian. Otherwise, if $|Y|>2$ then $Y \cap Z(X) = 1$, so $|YZ(X)/Z(X)| > 2$ and the inductive hypothesis applied to $X/Z(X)$ gives a contradiction.